# Estimating median from quantized data

Tags: order-statistics

I have quantized measurements and I would like to estimate the median of the underlying distribution.  Can I do better than taking the median of the quantized measurement?

Comment: If you know something about the underlying distribution, you can do better: eg if the measurements are variates from a normal distribution which have all been rounded to the nearest integer, you can find a best-fitting normal and take its median. The median of the observations will always be an integer or half-integer, but the underlying median can be an arbitrary real.

Comment: @Matt f. I was hoping for a non-parametric approach